# Python dataframe issue

Tags: python, pandas, imdb

I have the following dataframe. It is from imdb. What i need to do is to extract movies with a score lower than 5 that receive more than 100000 votes. My problem is that I dont understand what the last code lines about the **voting** really do.

```
# two lists, one for movie data, the other of vote data
movie_data=[]
vote_data=[]
# this will do some reformating to get the right unicode escape for 
hexentityMassage = [(re.compile('&#x([^;]+);'), lambda m: '&#%d;' % int(m.group(1), 16))] # converts XML/HTML entities into unicode string in Python
for i in range(20):
    next_url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?sort=num_votes,desc&start=%d&title_type=feature&year=1950,2012'%(i*50+1)
    r = requests.get(next_url)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text,convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES,markupMassage=hexentityMassage)
    # movie info is found in the table cell called 'title'
    for movie in bs.findAll('td', 'title'):
        title = movie.find('a').contents[0].replace('&amp;','&') #get '&' as in 'Batman & Robin'
        genres = movie.find('span', 'genre').findAll('a')
        year = int(movie.find('span', 'year_type').contents[0].strip('()'))
        genres = [g.contents[0] for g in genres]
        runtime = movie.find('span', 'runtime').contents[0]
        rating = float(movie.find('span', 'value').contents[0])
        movie_data.append([title, genres, runtime, rating, year])
    # rating info is found in a separate cell called 'sort_col'
    for voting in bs.findAll('td', 'sort_col'):
        vote_data.append(int(voting.contents[0].replace(',','')))
```

Comment: You've tagged this `pandas`, but it looks like you aren't using it in this code snippet and this is mostly `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Why did you include the first loop since it is unrelated to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this snippet,

```
for voting in bs.findAll('td', 'sort_col'):
    vote_data.append(int(voting.contents[0].replace(',','')))
```

Here you are looping over all the `td` tags which have a attribute `sort_col`. In this case they have `class="sort_col"`.

In the second line,

- you are replacing the `','` with `''` (empty string) of the first element of the list returned by  `voting.contents`.
- casting it to `int`.
- then appending it to `vote_data`.

If I break this up, It will be like this,

```
for voting in bs.findAll('td', 'sort_col'):
    # voting.contents returns a list like this [u'377,936']
    str_vote = voting.contents[0]
    # str_vote will be '377,936' 
    int_vote = int(str_vote.replace(',', ''))
    # int_vote will be 377936
    vote_data.append(int_vote)
```

Print the values in the loop to get more understanding. If you tagged your question right you might get a good answer faster.